# JSON JWT Token Object - Malformed UTF-8 data - Crypto JS

Tags: javascript, json, encryption, utf-8, cryptojs

I have encrypt my token and data json object like this and that's redirect to a subdomain web app with a guard angular :

```
// access website Wordpress/jQuery/Crypto-js 3.1.9-1
let encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(response), SECRET_PASSPHRASE);
window.location.href = APP_HOME + "?access=" + encrypted;
```

The redirection work's as well but I have this error when my guard try to deycrpt the "access" param.

```
Error: Malformed UTF-8 data
at Object.stringify (core.js:478)
at WordArray.init.toString (core.js:215)
at AuthGuard.push../src/app/_guards/auth/auth.guard.ts.AuthGuard.decryptData (auth.guard.ts:62)
at AuthGuard.push../src/app/_guards/auth/auth.guard.ts.AuthGuard.canActivate
```

My function to decrypt - Angular WebApp - I try a lot of variations because I find a lot of persons to have the same bug with this error "Malformed UTF-8 data'.

```
/* Angular - Crypto-js 3.1.9-1 */
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js'; 
...
decryptData(data) {
  try {
    const bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(data.toString(), this.encryptSecretKey);
    let decryptedData = JSON.parse(bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
    //let aa = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(bytes)
    // let aa = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    console.log('decryptedData ==>', decryptedData);
    return JSON.stringify(decryptedData);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: What, why are you decrypting your token in the Web, you should only decrypt the token on the server.  e.g you're giving them access to your secret this.encryptSecretKey

Comment: I don't decrypt the token, I just want to encrypt my localstorage data user (token, role,etc. json object) to set the same data in other localstorage linked to other domain name.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, What is the purpose of encrypting the localstorage you will have to keep the encryption key on the web, e.g your encryption key is exposed, if you're using an asymmetric key it will only work one way.  So what are you trying to gain out of this?

Comment: addtionally you probably don't want to put your access token in the URL, this poses a security risk